# Having the same font for both the caption and the main document

Tags: fonts

[image: First part: caption; Second part: main body]

I would like to have the same font family & style for both the caption and the main body. My code for the caption is the following (note that I didn't specify to change the font family):

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\graphicspath{{images/}}
\usepackage[format=plain,labelfont=default,textfont={it}]{caption}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[htp]
        \centering
        \includegraphics{HIII.png}
        \caption{Hybrid III crash test dummy. blablalblabllbalalbalbla blabla balbal lbal allal}
        \label{fig:hiii}
\end{figure}
\noindent Figure 1: \textit{Hybrid III crash test dummy. blablalblabllbalalbalbla blabla balbal lbal allal}

\end{document}
```

Comment: See the `caption` package that allows to change the caption fonts, please -- and welcome to TeX.SX!

Comment: Use \usepackage{lmodern} instead of the fontfamily command.

Comment: The problen is your `{\fontfamily{lmr}\selectfont` which is wrong you have not changed the default family for the document so headings captions and lots of other features will still use computer modern. use the package as Ulrike said,

Comment: It will have changed, but your image is showing the caption (not capture) in italic, the report class does not set captions in italic so that is some code that you have not shown. Please always post a full (small) document that produces the image that you post,

Comment: oh the italic is because of the `,textfont={it}]{caption}` which you put in a comment but not shown in your code example

Comment: The posted code now does not produce the image shown, the caption uses upright text and the text version after the figure uses italic because of the `\textit`

Comment: unrelated but you should delete the `{` before `\centering` and the matching `}` and use `[htp]` not `[h]`

Comment: you've solved the problem, but the code you show can't possibly produce the example -- the caption in the example is times, and the text font is modern.

Comment: Isn't the output the same? What's the question?

Comment: Now the code, the ouptut and the title should match. The problem (having the same font for both the caption and the main document) is solved. The solution was given by Ulrike Fischer and the problem in the original code (code that I deleted because of barbara beeton's remarks) was spotted by David Carlisle. For people having the same necessity: the reported code, now, produces the picture. The relevant posts about the specific problem in my original (wrong) code are the first three.

Comment: @Joob -- the problem with this now is that there is no longer a clear question, so it's not going to help anyone else.  it's okay to make edits to a question, but whatever the error was needs to be clearly visible.  your original output *did* show a problem, but the code didn't match, so no one could replicate it.  if a problem can be replicated with the code you post, then someone can solve it.